# How to assign variables with the same names more effectively in C++?

Tags: c++, mapping, variable-assignment

For instance, I have the class:

```
class SimpleClass
{
  int fieldOne;
  int fieldTwo;
  int fieldThree;
}
```

Some part of mine code requires to copy this variable into own fields, but one thing is that I want to assign the same named variables

```
void AnotherClass::copyFields(SimpleClass& buf)
{
     fieldOne = buf.fieldOne;
     fieldTwo = buf.fieldTwo;
     fieldThree = buf.fieldThree;
}
```

As you can see I just fill the same named variables. Can I use this "the same named" feature and not rewrite variable names but implement some mapping and make easy the such assignment?

Comment: If you have two different types with an identical bunch of fields, then your design has a hole. Fix it, or you will be pumping out water forever,

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to "fix" your design such that you do not need to assign the members manually: inheritance, composition or perhaps those two classes are actually one and the same.

With composition:

```
struct fields {
    int fieldOne;
    int fieldTwo;
    int fieldThree;
};

struct SimpleClass {
    fields f;
};

struct AnotherClass {
    fields f;
    void copyFields(const SimpleClass& s) {
        f = s.f;
    }
};
```

If this is not an option, I see no other way than using a macro, but you will still need to type almost the same amount of code:

```
void AnotherClass::copyFields(SimpleClass& buf)
{
     ASSIGN(fieldOne,buf);
     ASSIGN(fieldTwo,buf);
     ASSIGN(fieldThree,buf);
}
```

C++ has no reflection, so there is no automagic way to iterate members of a class in C++.

Comment: The example with composition does not quite answer the quiestion. `SimpleClass` members now have to be access through intermediate `f` member, and this is not always acceptable. As for general 'design smell' comment, there are also valid cases when one has to do it (most straightforward - both structs are outside of developer's contol).

Comment: @SergeyA hum true, thats why I start with suggesting to change the design, but thats just a cheap excuse ;)

Comment: I think, this is genuinely a failure of C++ committee to fail to provide compile-time reflection for all those years.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for agreeing that it isnt my fault. Sorry, just joking, I tried to find a way but I think it isnt possible with something that is actually less to type than the originial. First idea was member pointers, but `&A::foo`  has no relation to `&B::foo`

Comment: Yeah, there is no way. Which is truly and utterly a disgrace. I can rant forever about it.